# How to get hex code directly from jscolor?

Tags: color-picker, jscolor

I'm trying to build a canvas app with color picker using jscolor.
Here are what I've done:

1. Included the file jscolor.js
2. Created a button with class="jscolor"

Code for the button:

```
<button id="strokeCol" class="jscolor {valueElement:'color_value'}" onchange="config.changeStrokeCol(this.jscolor)">
   Stroke Color
</button>
```

When I select a color from the picker I can see the background color of the button changing in developer tool, but in RGB value. Read it somewhere else that I can simply get the HEX by specifying `$('element').val()`, but in my case it just gives me `""` (blank).

The HTML also has no value attribute triggered by the click, not to say being updated. The examples only shows that I can specify a default value (which can't be updated as well).

Have I missed anything? Or has jscolor been updated to provide only RGB value through the background color?

The only workaround I can think of is allowing the HEX code to be displayed inside the button then use `.html()` to get the value, but it seems so unnecessary.

Comment: Here's the code of the button: <button id="strokeCol" class="jscolor {valueElement:'color_value'}" onchange="config.changeStrokeCol(this.jscolor)">Stroke Color</button>

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when class is inserted to the
    `<input>` tag. Strange!